# Django ORM. Select only duplicated fields from DB

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-orm

I have table in DB like this:

```
MyTableWithValues
id | user(fk to Users) | value(fk to Values) |   text     | something1 | something2 ...
1  | userobject1       | valueobject1        |asdasdasdasd| 123        | 12321
2  | userobject2       | valueobject50       |QWQWQWQWQWQW| 515        | 5555455
3  | userobject1       | valueobject1        |asdasdasdasd| 12345      | 123213
```

I need to delete all objects where are repeated fields **user, value** and **text**, but save one from them. In this example will be deleted 3rd record.

How can I do this, using Django ORM?

PS:
try this:

```
recs = (
        MyTableWithValues.objects
        .order_by()
        .annotate(max_id=Max('id'), count_id=Count('user__id'))
        #.filter(count_id__gt=1)
        .annotate(count_values=Count('values'))
        #.filter(count_icd__gt=1)
)
    ...
    ...
    for r in recs:
        print(r.id, r.count_id, , r.count_values)
```

it prints something like this:

```
1 1 1
2 1 1
3 1 1
...
```

Dispite the fact, that in database there are duplicated values. I cant understand, why Count function does not work.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first be aware of how **count** works.
The Count method will count for **identical rows**.
It uses all the **fields** available in an object to check if it is identical with fields of **other rows** or not.
So in current situation the **count_values** is resulting **1** because Count is using all fields excluding **id** to look for similar rows.
Count is including user,value,text,something1,something2 fields to check for similarity.

**To count rows with similar fields you have to use only user,values & text field**

Query:

```
  recs = MyTableWithValues.objects
         .values('user','values','text')
         .annotate(max_id=Max('id'),count_id=Count('user__id'))
         .annotate(count_values=Count('values'))
```

It will return a list of dictionary

```
  print(recs)
```

Output:

```
<QuerySet[{'user':1,'values':1,'text':'asdasdasdasd','max_id':3,'count_id':2,'count_values':2},{'user':2,'values':2,'text':'QWQWQWQWQWQW','max_id':2,'count_id':1,'count_values':1}]
```

using this **queryset** you can check how many times a **row** contains user,values & text field with same values

Answer (score 0):

Would a Python loop work for you?

```
import collections

d = collections.defaultdict(list)

# group all objects by the key
for e in MyTableWithValues.objects.all():
    k = (e.user_id, e.value_id, e.text)
    d[k].append(e)

for k, obj_list in d.items():
    if len(obj_list) > 1:
        for e in obj_list[1:]:
            # except the first one, delete all objects
            e.delete()
```

Comment: I could use this, but database query works a lot faster, than python code. I have DB with thousands values, and I need a high-speed code :)